# How to put text over Image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

So I'm new to react-native (and javascript in general), I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

So basically this is an image with text over it but slightly going out of the image top.

And this is what I get : [What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRu5f.png)

As you can see the text is not rendered when it is out of the image.

This is the code I use :

```
class Test extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.matchContainer}>
        <Image source={ require('../../res/img/lol_wallpaper.jpg') } style={styles.backgroundImage}>
          <View style={styles.topContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.topText}>text</Text>
            <Text style={styles.topText}>text</Text>
          </View>
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the css :

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  matchContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    width: width,
    height: 300,
    marginTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
topText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(86, 203, 83)',

    padding: 2,
    position: 'relative',
  },
topContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,

    top: -10,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    width: width - 10,
    height: 138,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess why you can't get your ideal answer because the *Text* is in the *Image* component. So when some part is out of the *Image* wouldn't display.

My method is use the property *position*.
There is the simple example I just created.
https://rnplay.org/apps/rpv82A

And remember the property *z-index* in react-native is depending on the render order. 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/698

Comment: Any chance you have a copy of this example still that you can embed directly here? The rnplay link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

### You can achieve this by using the following CSS property:

**`position`**

By using this method, you'll just use 3 elements: `div`, `img` and `h2`

> HTML

```
<div class="img-box">
    <img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/league-of-legends-wallpaper/league-of-legends-wallpaper-20.jpg" />
    <h2>TEXT</h2>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.img-box {
margin-top: 50px;
width: 450px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
}

.img-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.img-box h2 {
    width: 125px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25%;
    left: 5%;
    font-size: 28pt;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: limegreen
}
```

#### After you try out this code, you can change the values in the CSS to follow your needs, since you respect this structure.

```css
.img-box {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.img-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.img-box h2 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 28pt;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: limegreen
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/league-of-legends-wallpaper/league-of-legends-wallpaper-20.jpg" />
  <h2>TEXT</h2>
</div>
```